# Detecting the source of the script call

Tags: php

I want to make sure that my site is accessible only from the local server, that is, I want to see the content of the page after clicking on the link. How to detect whether an address was called from a local server or from an external one?

Comment: Check if `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` are the same.